# How to revert the proxy settings (Chrome API) through Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hey I want to know how to use the following chrome API function to revert the chrome proxy settings through default

```
chrome.proxy.settings.clear(Objectparam, callbackparam)
```

What should the params contain. Can anyone explain?

This link may help [Link to chrome api documentation regarding chrome.proxy](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/proxy/)

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

While setting the Proxy , through Chrome API, Along with config params,
We're required to provide a scope seperately for it , as "regular" , "incognito_persistent" and "incognito_session_only"
which defines proxy settings scope as regular browser or in incognito.

In order to clear the same proxy, set on this specific scope
We provide as Params `{scope:"regular"}`
while callback params is just a simple function , to be called after clearing up proxy.
So, it will go like this

```
chrome.proxy.settings.clear({scope:'regular'},()=>console.log('Proxy Removed'));
```